# Load modules from other external webpack bundles by their npm module name

Tags: module, npm, webpack

Is it possible for a webpack bundle to load modules that are defined by other webpack bundles, without those bundles all having to be globally defined as a library (with `libraryTarget` and `library` in webpack config)?

Thus enabling me to reuse the original npm module names as the only reference to different modules.